# How to detect duplicate records in VB6?

Tags: vb6

If LastName and FirstName already exist, else add new, it's okay to duplicate the last name but different first name in the last record.

Example:

**First Record**

*Last Name = Bautista*

*First Name = Johnlord*

**Second Record**

*Last Name = Bautista*

*First Name = Angelo*

**Third Record**

*Last Name = Domingo*

*First Name = Angelo*

**Fourth Record**

*Last Name = Domingo*

*First Name = Johnlord*

**SAVE!**

--

**First Record**

*Last Name = Bautista*

*First Name = Angelo*

**Second Record**

*Last Name = Bautista*

*First Name = Angelo*

**ALREADY EXIST!**

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

With Adodc1.Recordset
If Text2.Text = "" Or Text3.Text = "" Or Text4.Text = "" Or Text5.Text = "" Or Text6.Text = "" Or Text7.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Update the Information Given!", vbCritical, "ASAP"
Else
MsgBox "Saved!", vbInformation, "Save"
End If`
.AddNew
.Fields(0) = Text2.Text
.Fields(1) = Text3.Text
.Fields(2) = Text4.Text
.Fields(3) = Combo1.Text
.Fields(4) = Text5.Text
.Fields(5) = Text6.Text`
.Fields(6) = Text7.Text
.Fields(7) = Text8.Text

Frame1.Visible = False
Text2.Text = "" 
Text3.Text = ""
Text4.Text = ""
Text5.Text = ""
Text6.Text = ""
Text7.Text = ""
Text8.Text = ""
Combo1.Text = ""
End If
End With
End Sub
```

This is my Interface:

[image: This is my Interface]

Comment: Tips: (1) your forms and text input boxes can be given explicit names. Don't call them `Text1`, `Text2`, etc, call them `txtFirstName`, `txtLastName`, etc. (2) your code would be more readable with some indentation.

Comment: Are you stuck on how to do the duplicate name detection? If so, where do you want to store the names - to a database, a file, an array?

Comment: Please help me :)

Comment: What do you need help with _specifically_?

Comment: Create a scripting dictionary. Add your data that you don't want duplicated to the key. It will error if key already exists. So you know it's a dup.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    On Error Resume Next
    Line=Inp.readline
    Dict.Add Line, ""
    If Err.Number <> 0 then
        Msgbox "a dup"
    End If
Loop
For Each thing in Dict.Keys()
    Outp.writeline thing
Next
```

This is reading from a textstream object (from File System Object) and writing unique records.